# Cannot convert the expression's type () to type Int - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am new to swift and iOS development. I am learning about passing data through multiple view controllers.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "mySegue") {
        var destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as FirstQuestionViewController
        destinationViewController.correctAnswerNumber = correctAnswerLabel.text
    }
}
```

I know that I can't convert this to an Int, but how would I go about going around this error?

In the trivia game, I want to have a summary page that says, "You did well" or "Brush up on your trivia before next game" depending on how well they did. I am trying to pass the `correctAnswerNumber` variable through 6 view controllers to the game summary page.

#### Questions

1. How do I get around this error?
2. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is there a better way to do this? Yes, using NSNumberFormatter.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer for Question 1

You are passing string to a integer variable. You need to change:

```
destinationViewController.correctAnswerNumber = correctAnswerLabel.text
```

to

```
let answerNumber : Int?                       = correctAnswerLabel.text.toInt()
destinationViewController.correctAnswerNumber = answerNumber!
```

#### Answer for Question 2

If you need to pass the variable to six ViewControllers, it's better to use a common shared storage.
I mean using a Singleton or `NSUserDefaults` will be a good idea, rather than passing it to six different ViewController like this.

Comment: Next error: "Value of optional type "Int?" not unwrapped; did you mean to use ? or !" 
I tried adding both of them but nothing worked. What next?